# timestamp conversion issue in oracle

Tags: oracle, timezone

I am trying to convert data from oracle date field which is in local eastern time to UTC format 
and I'm using below function to achieve it

```
CAST("date field" AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

and my output looks like below

```
06-NOV-19 09.55.21.000000 AM
```

However i need to format the output to below format

```
11/6/2019 9:55:21.000000000 AM
```

Is there an oracle function which i directly use to do above format conversion?

Comment: [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is not a *format*.  It is a system of timekeeping.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting and the actual value are separate things. The value, you say is correct, however you want it to look in a different style than the default.

Look into TO_CHAR if you want a specifically formatted string output. eg:

```
SELECT TO_char(cast(sysdate as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ssxFF am') from dual;

11/18/2019 07:39:42.000000 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried on my database and the same consult turn the expected result. Try to confer this web site that will show the config of date in oracle:
http://blog.marvinsiq.com/2018/08/23/formatar-data-e-hora-no-oracle-sql-developer/